# Python Classes: Variable subclass creation in the base class's methods

Tags: python

Here's the coding problem I am trying to solve...  I have a base class, let's say Animal, and it has two subclasses, say Dog and Cat.  My class Animal has a method, make_baby(), that both Dog and Cat will inherit.  The trick I'm having trouble pulling off is that I want the return value to be a new instance of the subclass that called the function but with different attribute values, i.e. Dog.make_baby() should return a new Dog and Cat.make_baby() will return a new Cat.

I previously tried returning "type(self)()", but this is no good because type() return a type object, not a class.

Here is the full example code:

```
Class Animal():
  def __init__(self, color):
    self.color = color
  def make_baby():
    new_color = rand_color # a randomly chosen color
    return #??? new class of the same type that called the method

Class Dog(Animal):
  def pet():
    print '*pant*'

Class Cat(Animal):
  def pet():
    print 'purrr'
```

So I'd like to avoid writing a make_baby() method for Dogs and Cats because the idea is that the method is exactly the same except for the returned class.  I'd also like to avoid a bunch of if statements because I'd like to make and arbitrarily large number of subclasses to Animal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You wrote:

> this is no good because type() return a type object, not a class.

A type *is* a class, if you're using new-style classes.  If you're using Python 3, you're set; all Python 3 classes are "new-style." If you're using Python 2.x, derive your class from `object` (or from something else that derives from object, like any built-in Python type).

But what you really want here is a class method, where you get a reference to the class passed in automatically.

```
class Animal(object):

  def __init__(self, color):
    self.color = color

  @classmethod
  def make_baby(cls):
    return cls(rand_color)   # randomly-chosen color
```

You can call it on the class (e.g. `Animal.make_baby()` or `Dog.make_baby()`) or on an instance; either way the method still receives the class as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks!  This was really bugging me because I actually had my real code working with the use of type(self)(...), but then it inexplicably stopped working.  I've realized that it was because my base class was originally a subclass of list and I decided that didn't make sense so I removed that and left it without a parent class.  I've added object as the parent class and it works again!  I'm going to play with the @classmethod suggestion you made, that sounds like a slick idea.  Thanks again.

Comment: A classmethod won't be appropriate if instances are required, e.g. if genetics are involved. Although in that case, with dynamic typing there won't be a natural way to prevent interspe - you know what, forget I said anything.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: You must be referring to Python's well-known "f\*ck typing".

Answer (score 3):

type() can be used to construct entirely new classes. What you want is:

```
class Animal():
  def __init__(self, color):
    self.color = color

  def make_baby(self):
    new_color = rand_color # a randomly chosen color
    return self.__class__(new_color)
```

Comment: Old-style classes, yuck. `type(instance)` will return a class with new-style.

Comment: Unless you're using Python 3 of course, but he clearly isn't.

Answer (score 3):

You approach will totally work! Just use new style classes.

```
Class Animal(object):
  def __init__(self, color):
    self.color = color
  def make_baby(self):
    new_color = rand_color # a randomly chosen color
    return type(self)(new_color)

Class Dog(Animal):
  def pet():
    print '*pant*'

Class Cat(Animal):
  def pet():
    print 'purrr'
```

However, if `make_baby(self)` is *not* relying on details of `self`, what you want is a class-wide factory method, like in @Kindall's answer.